# Electron and Sqlite: SQLITE_NOTADB: file is not a database

Tags: sql, sqlite, electron, knex.js

I try to build an Electron.js app with sqlite database containing already prepared dataset. I have created a stock.db file first via sqlite3 command and then dumped it this way:

> sqlite3 stocks.db .dump > stocks.sqlite

The stocks.sqlite syntax is pretty straightforward:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "records" (
    "TICKER"    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "DAY"   varchar(155) NOT NULL,
    "TIME"  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "OPEN"  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "HIGH"  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "LOW"   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "CLOSE" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "VOL"   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "id"    int(11) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO "records" VALUES...
CREATE TABLE "symbols" (
    "id"    int(11) NOT NULL,
    "name"  varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "symbol"    varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO "symbols" VALUES...
```

Then I place this file into my electron directory and attempt to invoke it within my code with knex:

```
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: "sqlite3",
    connection: {
        filename: "./stocks.sqlite"
    }
})

let resault = knex.select('symbol', 'name').from('symbols')
        resault.then(rows => {
            console.log(rows)
            win.webContents.send('resultSend', rows)
})
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

and then my system do not recognize it as a proper sqlite file:

> [Error: select `symbol`, `name` from `symbols` - SQLITE_NOTADB: file
> is not a database] {   errno: 26,   code: 'SQLITE_NOTADB' }

What do I do wrong here? How I should fix my .sqlite file to be a readable for my app.

Comment: Well it isn't a database is it? It is just a create script for a database, so you should point it at a `.db` file. With sqlite you can just take a copy of the `stocks.db` file, if you can't work with the original.

Comment: Oh boy... You're right. I've just replaced .sqlite file with .db and now everything seems to work just fine. This is kinda unintuitive since knex.js docs suggest precisely .sqlite format is required. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating SQL dump from your database `stocks.sqlite`, instead of using the actual database file you have created earlier.

If you want to create a new sqlite3 DB with knex migrations you can set `knex` to use some non-existing file and initialize the table with `knex.schema.*` APIs. Though using precreated database is just fine.

I saw that in comments you mention, that one should use `database.sqlite` named file. That is perfectly fine too, just rename the database binary file to have `.sqlite` extension.

From google all the fileinfo pages seem to mention that `.sqlite` is actually the binary database file and not plain SQLite compatible textual `.sql` dump.

https://file.org/extension/sqlite
http://www.manifold.net/doc/mfd9/sqlite.htm

Though sqlite3 docs doesn't force any file extension that should be used. Except that for maximum compatibility they mention that 8+3 chars in the name is the best.